# Logging a user on from one table & count occurrences from another in same statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I'm making a small php website that allows users to log on and one of the features is it allows them to post messages to each other. The **messages table** is described below:

```
msgId   int(20) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
mSender int(20) NO  MUL NULL    
mReciever   int(20) NO  MUL NULL    
mTitle  tinytext    NO      NULL    
mBody   mediumtext  NO      NULL    
mRead   tinyint(4)  NO      NULL    
mDate   datetime    NO      NULL
```

When the users log on they are authenticated against details stored in this table:

```
aId int(20) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
aUser   varchar(30) NO  UNI NULL    
aPass   varchar(40) NO      NULL    
aEmail  varchar(30) NO  UNI NULL    
aBio    mediumtext  YES     NULL    
aReg    datetime    NO      NULL
```

I use a `select` statement to compare the result set to the *credentials* supplied by the user, if *authenticated* i would like to display in the `header.php` file some status such as how many messages if any, the only way i have been able to do this is via a seperate select count on the `messages` table.

Would there be a way of combining both, so the user credentials are matched but also the number of unread messages are displayed. I record messages for users in the messages table using the mReciever field, and the read can either be 1 or 0 to indicate read or not. THe count statement is: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS occurrences FROM messages WHERE mRead=0 and mReciever=$aId`  and the authors logon one is a simple `select * from authors` where user and password match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT a.aId,
       a.aEmail,
       a.aBio,
       a.aReg,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM messages 
         WHERE mRead=0 AND mReciever=a.aId) occurrences
  FROM authors a
 WHERE a.aEmail = 'email@mail.com' AND a.aPass = '*****'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a36fb/7)**